# Checking for an image in a loop with Sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli

I have a script in Sikuli that is a bot. It looks like this:

```
for i in range (100):
    find(YoutubeChannelButton)
    click(YoutubeChannelButton)
    wait(3)
    while(1): 
        if exists(LikeButton):
            click(LikeButton)
            wait(6)
            click(Close)
            wait(10)
        else:
            click(Close)
            wait(5)
```

I want it to click the "like" button if it exists and when it doesn't exist I want it to click on the close button and then retry the process all over again.

So in summary:

- It checks for an image
- If it is not there it closes the current window
- Then it restarts the process all over again.

The problem is that it does the job one time (correctly) and then it starts closing all the pages.

Comment: What is "close" exactly? If that's the whole page obviously that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We'd have to see some screenshots of what you're working with to be sure, but it looks to me like you've set up your loop wrong.  If the LikeButton doesn't exist, it clicks close and restarts the loop.  Unless the window behind the current one has a LikeButton, it *still* won't exist, so we'll close that window too, and so on.

Why don't you write it as

```
for i in range (100):
    find(YoutubeChannelButton)
    click(YoutubeChannelButton)
    wait(3)
    if exists(LikeButton):
        click(LikeButton)
        wait(6)
        click(Close)
        wait(10)
    else:
        click(Close)
        wait(5)
```